# Display an alert if the form has errors on submit in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'm using `react-final-form` and I would like to display an alert if a user tries to submit a form with errors. But I don't know how to do it. I've made a function for form onSubmit like this:

```
onSubmit={event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  //How to check if the form has any validation  errors?
  if () {
    alert("Errors");
  } else {
    handleSubmit();
  }
}}
```

How can I check in it if there are any validation errors? Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-submission-errors-example-zbl6h?fontsize=14).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of possible ways to do it. Here's one:

```
<form
  onSubmit={event => {
    if (invalid) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(errors, undefined, 2));
    }
    handleSubmit(event);
  }}
>
  ...fields
</form>
```

[image: Edit React Final Form - Synchronous Record Level Validation]

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in onSubmit method by checking every validation on form values.

Instead, use validate prop which is mentioned in doc:

```
validate?: (value: ?any, allValues: Object, meta: ?FieldState) => ?any
```

This will let you define rules on individual fields and validate value before submitting a call.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I already have validation set up with validate prop. But my form is long. So I need to show an alert on submit, if there is any error, so that the user knows, that he needs to go back and check the fields.